# Only the first value in the JSON saved to Database - Laravel

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, arraylist, eloquent

I am receiving the data from a form where I am trying to save the data to the database.

While saving the first record is saved multiple times.

```
return response()->json($request->all());
```

**JSON**

```
{
   "product_combo_name":"asdfadsf",
   "product_values":"[{\"product_data\":{\"id\":1,\"slug\":\"product-name\",\"sku\":\"product-code\",\"product_name\":\"Product Name\",\"category_id\":1,\"subcategory_id\":1,\"previewImg\":\"http:\/\/localhost\/EcommerceBackend\/public\/\/assets\/images\/product\/thumb\/Product Name.jpeg\",\"hasVariants\":false,\"deleted_at\":null,\"created_at\":\"2020-09-17T07:17:42.000000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2020-09-17T10:54:24.000000Z\"},\"product_qty\":\"1\",\"product_price\":\"100\",\"product_tax\":\"18\",\"hsn_code\":\"78877\",\"product_line_total\":\"118.00\"},{\"product_data\":{\"id\":1,\"slug\":\"product-name\",\"sku\":\"product-code\",\"product_name\":\"Product Name\",\"category_id\":1,\"subcategory_id\":1,\"previewImg\":\"http:\/\/localhost\/EcommerceBackend\/public\/\/assets\/images\/product\/thumb\/Product Name.jpeg\",\"hasVariants\":false,\"deleted_at\":null,\"created_at\":\"2020-09-17T07:17:42.000000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2020-09-17T10:54:24.000000Z\"},\"product_qty\":\"1\",\"product_price\":\"100\",\"product_tax\":\"18\",\"hsn_code\":\"197797\",\"product_line_total\":\"118.00\"}]",
   "shipping_charges":"123",
   "total_price":"359.00",
   "combo_total_price":"124.18",
   "product_total_price":"236.00",
   "charge_breakup":"[{\"name\":\"qty\",\"qty\":\"1\",\"per_unit_price\":\"1\",\"tax\":\"18\",\"tax_amount\":\"0.18\",\"line_total_amount\":\"1.18\"}]"
}
```

I am trying to save the product_data as individual value, but the JSON Seems to be bit complex to me.

When I run foreach in Laravel Controller Only the first object is returned,

```
foreach (json_decode($request->product_values) as $key => $value) {
    # code...
    Product::insert([
    'product_id' => $value->id,
    ]);

    return response()->json(json_encode($value->product_data->id));
}

Response : "1"
```

The Same behaviour for the charge_breakup. Not sure how to break this JSON Response.

Edit 1:

```
$value = json_decode($request->product_values);

    return response()->json($value);
```

Json Response:

```
[{"product_data":{"id":1,"slug":"product-name","sku":"product-code","product_name":"Product Name","category_id":1,"subcategory_id":1,"previewImg":"http:\/\/localhost\/EcommerceBackend\/public\/\/assets\/images\/product\/thumb\/Product Name.jpeg","hasVariants":false,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2020-09-17T07:17:42.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-09-17T10:54:24.000000Z"},"product_qty":"1","product_price":"100","product_tax":"18","hsn_code":"78877","product_line_total":"118.00"},{"product_data":{"id":1,"slug":"product-name","sku":"product-code","product_name":"Product Name","category_id":1,"subcategory_id":1,"previewImg":"http:\/\/localhost\/EcommerceBackend\/public\/\/assets\/images\/product\/thumb\/Product Name.jpeg","hasVariants":false,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2020-09-17T07:17:42.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-09-17T10:54:24.000000Z"},"product_qty":"1","product_price":"100","product_tax":"18","hsn_code":"197797","product_line_total":"118.00"}]
```

Comment: You only get the first ID because you're returning within the foreach. Have you tried moving the return statement?

Comment: Don't return inside the loop, It'll break the loop at first run only

Comment: Updated the question with the results outside foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to why you only *seem* to get one item, is because you're returning inside the foreach.

```
foreach (json_decode($request->product_values) as $key => $value) {
    # code...
    Product::insert([
    'product_id' => $value->id,
    ]);

    return response()->json(json_encode($value->product_data->id));
}
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but to get a collection of id's:

```
$ids = array();
foreach (json_decode($request->product_values) as $key => $value) {
    # code...
    Product::insert([
    'product_id' => $value->id,
    ]);

    array_push($ids, json_encode($value->product_data->id));
}

return response()->json(collect($ids));
```